# Are SATA controllers SAS compatible?

Tags: sata, adapter, sas

I have a couple old SAS drives that I want to wipe to resell, along with their RAID controller card.

However, the PC they came with is toast, and my personal rig has only SATA-III  ports. I can buy a physical adapter on amazon or reuse the old RAID card, but I am wondering if the SATA controller on my mobo can even make the connection?

relevant specs:
aorus ultra z390
i7-9700k
16gb ram
windows 10
nvidia gpu

Comment: I had a similar problem two years ago, but was unable to find a cheap external USB SAS connectors.  Unfortunately, most consumer motherboards do not have SAS compatibility.  The physical connector is the same.  You'll need a cheap PCI RAID card with SAS compatibility.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I salvaged the RAID card as well, but I am having trouble finding info on how to set it up

Answer (score 3):

No. An SAS (Serially Attached SCSI) controller is needed to make changes to an SAS drive, despite the [partial similarity in connectors](https://images.app.goo.gl/fjSrGK2yxDyx95UX7).

Often those controller cards need additional drivers installed to function with Windows 10. That's on a card-by-card basis, so for a particular make and model of card, consult its documentation.

Comment: quick follow up: I salvaged the SAS raid controlled from the computer as well, which is PCIE. having all the components, is it as simple as popping the raid controller in, and then navigating to disk managment, and deleting from there?

Comment: That RAID controller may need drivers. Search the web for its documentation, and if it requires special drivers for Windows 10, install them. If you don't find the documentation, click [edit] and put the make and model of the card into your question so we can see what you have, and help find instructions.

Comment: If no Windows drivers are available, I'd try using a bootable Linux CD and wiping the drives from there.  For older hardware, Linux tends to have much better support than Windows.